# Can't connect wirelessly using redhat9

Tags: wireless-networking, redhat-enterprise-linux

I've recently installed redhat 9 and I'm trying to connect to the internet using a wireless card. I'm able to connect to the network and get to the router webpage @ 10.0.0.1 But whenever I open firefox to connect to web the page/server cannot be found error.

I tried going to terminal and using route add default gw 10.0.0.1 but still doesn't work

Comment: Is it possible you mean *Fedora* 9 (2008) or do you really mean Red Hat 9 (2003)? In either case, you should install something more recent, such as [Fedora 14](http://fedoraproject.org/).

Comment: i hope he doesn't mean redhat9

Answer (score 1):

Redhat 9? The one that was released in 2003? Yah, that's going to be a problem. Try a recent, modern linux distro and I'm sure you'll have much better luck.

Answer (score 1):

In agreement with ErikA I would suggest trying a newer distribution. Perhaps RHEL 6, CentOS 5.5 or Fedora 14.

That said if you have the link up and working then you have usually done the hardest part. Try checking the nameserver listed in /etc/resolv.conf is correct (particularly if you are doing static configuration).

Comment: I actually meant RHEL 6 not sure why I typed 9, probably was too tired.