# Can't connect wirelessly using redhat9

Tags: wireless-networking, redhat-enterprise-linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't connect wirelessly using redhat9](https://superuser.com/questions/213611/cant-connect-wirelessly-using-redhat9)

I've recently installed redhat 9 and I'm trying to connect to the internet using a wireless card. I'm able to connect to the network and get to the router webpage @ 10.0.0.1
But whenever I open firefox to connect to web the page/server cannot be found error.

I tried going to terminal and using route add default gw 10.0.0.1 but still doesn't work.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions, you will have better luck asking on [superuser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: "redhat 9"? As in Red Hat Linux 9? That's ancient. You'll almost certainly be better served by something newer.